# Joining a selected table to a cross joined table

Tags: sql, left-join, teradata, cross-join

I have a table, `flight_schedule`, that consists of a bunch of flight segments.  Below I have a Terradata SQL query that creates a list of two segment itineraries between Chicago and Denver.  i.e. each row has two flights that eventually get the passenger from Chicago to Denver.  For example, the first row contains flight information on a leg from Chicago to Omaha and then a later leg from Omaha to Denver.  This query works just fine.

```
SELECT A.flt_num, A.dprt_sta_cd, A.arrv_sta_cd, A.sch_dprt_dtml, A.sch_arrv_dtml, 
B.flt_num, B.dprt_sta_cd, B.arrv_sta_cd, B.sch_dprt_dtml, B.sch_arrv_dtml
FROM 
flight_schedule A 
CROSS JOIN 
flight_schedule B
WHERE
A.dprt_sta_cd = 'Chicago' AND
B.arrv_sta_cd = 'Denver' AND
A.arrv_sta_cd = B.dprt_sta_cd AND
A.sch_arrv_dtml < B.sch_dprt_dtml
ORDER BY B.sch_arrv_dtml;
```

I have another table, `flight_seat_inventory`, that consists of seats available in different cabins for each flight number.  The query below aggregates total available seats for each flight number.  This query is also A-OK.

```
SELECT flt_num, SUM(seat_cnt) as avail_seats
FROM flight_seat_inventory
GROUP BY flt_num;
```

I want to combine these two queries with a LEFT JOIN, twice, so that each flight has a corresponding `avail_seats` value.  How can I do this?

For added clarity, I think my desired `Select` statement looks like this:

```
SELECT A.flt_num, A.dprt_sta_cd, A.arrv_sta_cd, A.sch_dprt_dtml, A.sch_arrv_dtml, C.avail_seats
B.flt_num, B.dprt_sta_cd, B.arrv_sta_cd, B.sch_dprt_dtml, B.sch_arrv_dtml, D.avail_seats
```

`flight_schedule` is HUGE, so I suspect it's more efficient to do the `LEFT JOIN` after the `CROSS JOIN`.  Again, using Teradata SQL.

Thanks!

Comment: Lots of views, no comments....  Is something not clear?  Is the wall of text intimidating?

Comment: Create your sample table and generate your sample query this way it will be easy to understand more regarding your post. Use this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to declare the second seats query as a temporary table using a `WITH` command before I did the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
WITH tempSeatsTable AS (
SELECT flt_num, SUM(seat_cnt) as avail_seats  
FROM flight_seat_inventory
GROUP BY flt_num    
)

SELECT 
A.flt_num, A.dprt_sta_cd, A.arrv_sta_cd, A.sch_dprt_dtml, A.sch_arrv_dtml, C.avail_seats
B.flt_num, B.dprt_sta_cd, B.arrv_sta_cd, B.sch_dprt_dtml, B.sch_arrv_dtml, D.avail_seats

FROM 
flight_schedule A 
CROSS JOIN 
flight_schedule B
LEFT JOIN
tempSeatsTable C
ON A.flt_num = C.flt_num
LEFT JOIN
tempSeatsTable D
ON B.flt_num = D.flt_num

WHERE
A.dprt_sta_cd = 'Chicago' AND
B.arrv_sta_cd = 'Denver' AND
A.arrv_sta_cd = B.dprt_sta_cd AND
A.sch_arrv_dtml < B.sch_dprt_dtml
ORDER BY B.sch_arrv_dtml;
```